# Delete Column from spreadsheet using OpenXML

Tags: openxml

I was wanting to delete a column using openxml, I am able to clear the contents of the cell, but have been unable to find documentation to delete the column as to shift the other cells left when the column is deleted. How may I delete the column using openxml where it will shift the cells to the left?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that OpenXml has no way to delete a column on its own. Therefor to solve my problem I wrote a function that first removed the contents of the cells in the column I was deleting and then to set the cell reference of the columns that came behind the column I was deleting up a column.

Comment: Can you share me the code here... I need to delete certain columns from worksheet. I know, its been a long time.. if possible please share

Comment: I started with removing the cells, but apparently it's only clearing their contents, not removing them from sheet. How do you set the reference of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate for each row and remove the cell you need

```
private void RemoveCell(int rowIndex, int colIndex)
{
    SheetData sheetData = _worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>(); // get the sheet
    Row row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);
    if (row != null && row.Count() > colIndex)
        row.RemoveChild(row.ElementAt(colIndex));
}
```

Comment: That only clears the cells, but does not remove the column.